# Fill array with list of hours in a duration 24h-format

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

I have tow inputs to select an hourly range like the following:

```
<input type="text" id="from" name="from" value="1:00" />
<input type="text" id="to" name="to" value="20:00" />
```

I store the data in an array-like bellow using `jQuery`:

```
["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20"]
```

I found a way on how to do that if the **hour-to input is greater than hour-from** input than I di it as follow

```
let hoursTo = $('#to').val();
let hoursFrom = $('#from').val();
if (hoursFrom < hoursTo) {
        for (let i = hoursFrom; i <= hoursTo; i++) {
            runHoursArray.push(i.toString());
        }
    }else {
// need help in the store logic in order to cover nightshifts 
}
```

but this doesn't cover the nightshift, therefore, I need help to store the data like below.

**Expected result:**

if i choose from 19:00 to 2:00 it should show up like this:

```
["19","20","21","22","23","0","1","2"]
```

**Note: I only want to store hours**

Thanks.

Comment: So, make two loops in the else branch then? One from hoursTo to <= 23, and one from 0 to hoursFrom …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inspired by @CBroe comment I made it by doing it like this:

```
if (hoursFrom < hoursTo) {
        for (let i = hoursFrom; i <= (hoursTo + 1); i++) {
            if (i !== 24) {
                runHoursArray.push(i.toString());
            } else {
                runHoursArray.push("0");
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (let i = 0; i <= (hoursTo + 1); i++) {
            runHoursArray.push(i.toString());
        }
        if (hoursFrom > 12) {
            for (let j = hoursFrom; j <= 23; j++) {
                runHoursArray.push(j.toString());
            }
        } else {
            for (let i = hoursTo; i <= (hoursFrom + 1); i++) {
                runHoursArray.push(i.toString());
            }
        }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the explanation and with a huge number of assumptions, I am writing this answer.

Before writing the answer, I want you to correct this part. You need `.val()` for comparison. You aren't comparing the elements.

```
let hoursTo = $('#to').val();
let hoursFrom = $('#from').val();
```

If you wanna add the night shifts as well, then yes, you have to allow values like that. What you can do is, check the duration and if the duration isn't humanely, like 23 hours (no one will generally like to work for 23 hours), tell it's invalid.

To do this, you can do something like:

```js
let hoursFrom = +$('#from').val();
let hoursTo = +$('#to').val();

$("button").click(function () {
  if ((hoursFrom > hoursTo && hoursTo + 24 - hoursFrom <= 12) || hoursFrom <= hoursTo) {
    console.log("Valid");
  } else {
    console.log("Invalid");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="from" type="number" />
<input id="to" type="number" />
<button>Validate</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I corrected the `val()` you mentioned but I think you misunderstood the purpose of the question my issue is not in allowing the values my problem is in storing them.

Comment: @KamelMili Maybe... Can you clarify so that we both are in the same pace.  We both know there's some kind of communication gap. Happy to guide you better.

Comment: @KamelMili Ahhh, storing them... Okay, let me think... 